# how to get active index with accordionPanel using primefaces in backing bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

when i try to get active index any accordion panel then its always return -1 value. I am using primefaces 7.0 version.

When i try to enable form tag then it is not working with the process of flow step wise.

I have also try other solutions from stackoverflow but nothing tobe work for me.
Anyone have idea about this.

1.example.xhtml

```
<!-- <h:form> -->
                                      
    <ui:fragment
        rendered="#{not empty excursionResultsBean.excursionAvailabilities and not empty excursionResultsBean.excursionAvailabilities[0].excursionCategoryBeans}">
        <p:accordionPanel multiple="false"
            activeIndex="#{panelDisplayBean.index}" role="tablist"  id="indexId" cache="false" >

            <f:ajax event="tabChange"
                listener="#{excursionResultsBean.onTabChange}" update="@form"/>
            
            <ui:insert name="creditCardPanel1">
                <ui:include src="step1.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
            <ui:insert name="creditCardPanel2">
                <ui:include src="step2.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
            <ui:insert name="creditCardPanel3">
                <ui:include src="step3.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
            <ui:insert name="creditCardPanel4">
                <ui:include src="step4.xhtml" />
            </ui:insert>
            
            
        </p:accordionPanel>
    </ui:fragment>
    
    <ui:fragment
        rendered="#{empty excursionResultsBean.excursionAvailabilities or empty excursionResultsBean.excursionAvailabilities[0].excursionCategoryBeans}">
        <div>
            <p>Sorry! We're booked to capacity on your flight</p>
            Please share your travel details with us at <b><a
                href="mailto:guest.ss@ss.com">guest.ss@ss.com</a></b>,
            so that we can work on this specially for you! Or call
            
        </div>

    </ui:fragment>
<!-- </h:form> -->
```

method in bean

```
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
        UITabPanel tabView = (UITabPanel) event.getComponent();
        int activeTab = tabView.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab());
        System.out.println("Active index "+activeTab);
}
```

Comment: when i click on particular tab then that tab of index is getting -1. I want actual index which is i have clicked

Comment: At the line of this :- String clientId = event.getTab().getClientId(); getting NullPointerException.   event of tab object is get null. How to resolve this. @Jasper de Vries. Is there any version mismatch issue or something else...

Comment: Hmm could be a bug in AccordionPanel in 7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Tab`, or any `UIComponent`, doesn't have an implementation of the `equals(Object obj)` method. So `tabView.getChildren().indexOf(event.getTab())` will never give you the tab index (because it uses the `equals` method).

What you could do is check the `clientId` while looping over the children to find the tab index. Not though, that not each child is a `Tab` per se, so compensate for that.

```java
public void onTabChange(TabChangeEvent event) {
    UIComponent component = event.getComponent();
    String clientId = event.getTab().getClientId();
    int index = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < component.getChildCount(); i++) {
        UIComponent child = component.getChildren().get(i);
        // Not each child is a tab per se
        if (child instanceof Tab) {
            index++;
            if (clientId.equals(child.getClientId())) {
                // Found it, break out of the for loop
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("index " + index);
}
```

I've tested the code above with:

```html
<p:accordionPanel>
    <!-- comment -->
    <p:tab title="1"></p:tab>
    <!-- comment -->
    <p:tab title="2"></p:tab>
    <p:tab title="3"></p:tab>
    <p:ajax event="tabChange" listener="#{testView.onTabChange}"/>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Comment: getting NullPointerException in this line : - String clientId = event.getTab().getClientId();

Comment: Try with `p:ajax` instead of `f:ajax`.

Comment: sure i will try

Answer (score 2):

Seems to be working on Primefaces 10.0 Showcase here: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/accordionPanel.xhtml

Look at the Change Events example?

This is what I do:

```java
/**
    * Listens for tab change events and updates the active tab value.
    *
    * @param event TabChangeEvent
    */
   public void onTabChange(final TabChangeEvent event) {
      // get the tab view
      final TabView tabView = (TabView) event.getTab().getParent();

      final String tabName = event.getTab().getClientId();

      int i = 0;
      for (final UIComponent item : tabView.getChildren()) {
         if (item.getClientId().equalsIgnoreCase(tabName)) {
            form.setActiveTabIndex(i);
            return;
         } else {
            i++;
         }
      }
      LOG.debug("Selected tab {} could not be located!", event.getTab().getClientId());
   }
```